# Find duplicates objects with solr4 and Haystack

Tags: solr, django-haystack

I use the facet mode of solr to find duplicates. It works pretty well but I can't figure how to get objects id's.

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('text_string', limit=-1)
>>> sqs.facet_counts()
{
    'dates': {},
    'fields': {
        'text_string': [
            ('the red ballon', 4),
            ('my grand pa is an alien', 2),
            ('be kind rewind', 12),
        ],
    },
    'queries': {}
}
```

How can I get id of my objects 'the red ballon', 'my grand pa is an alien', etc. , do I have to add id field in the schema.xml of solr ?

I'm expecting something like that:

```
>>> sqs.facet_counts()
{
    'dates': {},
    'fields': {
        'text_string': [
            (object_id, 'the red ballon', 4),
            (object_id, 'my grand pa is an alien', 2),
            (object_id, 'be kind rewind', 12),
        ],
    },
    'queries': {}
}
```

**EDIT: Added schema.xml and search_indexes.py**

schema.xml for solr

```
...
  <fields>
    <!-- general -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
    <field name="django_ct" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored ="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false"/>

    <field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"  termVectors="true" />
    <field name="title" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"  />

    <!-- Used for duplicate content detection --> 
    <copyField source="title" dest="text_string" />
    <field name="text_string" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="pk" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

  </fields>

  <!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

  <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

  <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
...
```

searche_indexes.py

```
class VideoIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    pk = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='pk')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title', boost=1.125)

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return Video.on_site.all()

    def get_model(self):
            return Video
```

Comment: did you index the id field? if no you have to add it in the schema.xml..and if you want it in the result.. you can mention the same in the query...

Comment: if I add ID (pk) to schema.xml my query return error:   TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'pk'

Comment: is there already a field with name ID...? and did you restart & re-index the data after you modify the schema.xml

Comment: nope, I used pk instead of id to avoid this problem. I restarted solr and re-index yes.

Comment: can you share the schema.xml?

Comment: Yes I added schema.xml and search_indexes.py

Comment: Change the value for the unique tag from id to pk...

Comment: I just figured out that there is already an id field, at the top of the schema.xml :       <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>

Comment: If you don't want the same... Remove it... And add your own field...it would solve the issue

Comment: I want to get the id of each results. Actually the queryset doesn't return ids. The problem is somewhere here. Solr have an id field and should have indexed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109103/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-kollo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Faceting` is the arrangement of search results into categories (which are based on indexed terms). Within each category, `Solr` reports on the number of hits for relevant term, which is called a facet constraint. Faceting makes it easy for users to explore search results on sites such as movie sites and product review sites, where there are many categories and many items within a category.

Here is good example of it...

[faceting example by Yonik](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/)

[faceting example on solr wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Overview+of+Searching+in+Solr)

In your case you may need to fire a query again to get the id and othere details....